# Offset in bootstrap 4 for button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What to use instead of col-sm-offset in Bootstrap 4?

In bootstrap 3 I have been using this code for button aligned in center

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
 <button>SEND</button>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 4 offset were replaced with margins. And I can not get desired output. I have been using "col-sm-6 ml-sm-auto" and still it is not aligned in center under whole form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with mx

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mx-sm-auto">
 <button>SEND</button>
</div>
```